# Histogram equalisation code generates indexing error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, indices

I am implementing histogram equalisation of an image without using inbuilt functions, specifically `imhist` and `histeq`. I am only allowed to use `cumsum` and `hist` or `histcounts`.  I have a test function that checks my code for different values that I've added for reference.

This is my code:

```
function eq_img = histeq_contrast(img)
%input image data is assumed to be in range 0..1
image = img;
[m,n] = size(image);
L = 256;
H = histcounts(image(:),(0:256));
H = H.';
[counts] = H;
x = 0:255;
myCDF = cumsum(counts)/(m*n);
eqI = (L-1)*myCDF(double(image)+1);
eqI = uint8(eqI);
histMyOutput = histcounts(eqI,256);
eq_img = histMyOutput;
```

This is the error message that is generated

```
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in histeq_contrast (line 22)
eqI = (L-1)*myCDF(double(image)+1);
Error in histeq_test (line 16)
I1eq = histeq_contrast(I1);
```

For reference, my test function is:

```
%histeq_test test script%

I1 = imread('pout.tif');
I1=im2double(I1);

% damage contrast
I1=0.8*I1;

I1eq = histeq_contrast(I1);
figure
subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(I1); caxis([0 1]); title('Test Image 1'); axis equal tight
subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(I1eq); caxis([0 1]); title('Histeq Result');  axis equal tight
colormap(gray);

fprintf(1,'Min/max of input image  1: %3.3f %3.3f\n', min(I1(:)),max(I1(:)) );
fprintf(1,'Min/max of output image 1: %3.3f %3.3f\n', min(I1eq(:)),max(I1eq(:)) );

% damage contrast
I2 = I1*0.25 + 0.25;

I2eq = histeq_contrast(I2);
figure
subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(I2); caxis([0 1]); title('Test Image 2');  axis equal tight
subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(I2eq); caxis([0 1]); title('Histeq Result');  axis equal tight
colormap(gray);

fprintf(1,'Min/max of input image  2: %3.3f %3.3f\n', min(I2(:)),max(I2(:)) );
fprintf(1,'Min/max of output image 2: %3.3f %3.3f\n', min(I2eq(:)),max(I2eq(:)) );
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Your input image is:

```
I1 = imread('pout.tif');
I1=im2double(I1);

% damage contrast
I1=0.8*I1;
```

After `im2double`, `I1` contains values in the range 0-1. Inside your `histeq_contrast` function, on the line where you get an error message, you index using this image:

```
eqI = (L-1)*myCDF(double(image)+1);
```

Thus, you are indexing at non-integer locations, as the error message indicates. (Also, the conversion to `double` is not necessary, as it already was doubles.) Correct would be:

```
eqI = (L-1)*myCDF(round(image*255)+1);
```

Alternatively, don't use `im2double`.

Comment: The code outputs without any erros but the histogram is now damaged, Edited the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: @user6820366: please don’t change the question so much that my answer no longer answers it. If you want, you can edit it to improve it, but don’t make giving you an answer a moving target. I have rolled back the edit. You missed the `*255` in your update, which is important here. Also, what your function outputs is the histogram of the equalized image. Make it output `eqI` instead. I’m guessing that you didn’t write the code???

Comment: Apologies, I didnt know about editing, and yes I didnt write the full code, I was hoping to get the histogram before, then changing it to the output image as required.